# Comics in which a dying Silver Surfer temporarily granted Power Cosmic to humans

Tags: story-identification, marvel, comics, silver-surfer

I remember reading a comic in which the Silver Surfer temporarily granted Power Cosmic to humans. Here are the details I can recall:

- Silver Surfer was possibly dying.
- Power Cosmic looked like it was raining down to humans. In that scene, the Silver Surfer was on a skyscraper looking down.
- I am not sure whether entire mankind was affected or just a city.
- Power Cosmic expanded the minds of humans who could now see beyond traps of negative emotions or something.

It was a very emotional story. The dying Silver Surfer allowed humans to experience Power Cosmic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the mini-series *Silver Surfer: Requiem* (2007). From [Marvel's website](https://www.marvel.com/comics/issue/13446/silver_surfer_requiem_2007_1):

> For untold years Norrin Radd has surfed the galaxy. Now his ride is about to come to an end. Until then, the Silver Surfer would undertake his final voyage -- to the one destination that has always eluded him. His journey will end where it all began!

More precisely...

**Silver Surfer was possibly dying.**

Indeed, the Silver Surfer's skin had basically reached the warranty's end. Problem being, due to it being directly incorporated into Norrin's life systems, the guy beneath would die with it.

[image: Richard Reed tells Silver Surfer he's dying]

**Power Cosmic looked like it was raining down to humans. In that scene, the Silver Surfer was on a skyscraper looking down.**

In issue #2, Spider-Man tells the Silver Surfer that the world could change for the better if people were to realize what they can achieve, what freedom and peace truly are. Silver Surfer agrees to share the Power Cosmic so that such a thing happens, for five minutes only because longer could kill him. He broadcasts the power from a skyscraper:

[image: Power Cosmic on humanity]

Comment: This is a very good read indeed.